# Why do we start off with one rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Shouldn't users start with zero rep?  Shouldn't every single point be earned?

What is the reasoning behind starting off every user with a little rep, then making sure that they can't ever go below that?

Comment: Starting at 0 would still be starting at '1' ;)

Comment: ? I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: [Zero-based indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). Jokes aside, I figured starting at 1 reputation point was based on tradition. Many sites start off new users with 1 point.

Comment: @iglvzx Heehee... SE is large and important enough to set the standard, not just follow it.

Comment: We could also see this as receiving a rep point for joining ;)

Answer (score 8):

It's explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2625/133693).

> The StackOverflow team believes that everybody's special in their own way and doesn't deserve to have a negative self-esteem (aka reputation).
>
> A rep of zero or negative seemed cruel. Plus, everyone starts out as "a one" instead of "a zero".

Comment: Everyone is initialized and defined.  Awesome.

Comment: Could someone explain to me that last sentence? The German term for *zero* ("Null", and it didn't make learning to program easier) can also be used to refer to a person, then meaning *loser*, but I don't think that's what Jeff is referring to.

Comment: @DanielBeck Telling someone he's zero indeed means that, my understanding anyway.